# CKEditor Enhanced Image Plugin doesn't always get initialized correctly

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a problem with the initialization of images in CKEditor 4.5.4 with the Enhanced Image plugin (image2). The first time a CKEditor instance is being loaded, the images don't get initialized correctly. See picture [image not correctly initialised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba0Wx.png). The caption field does work correctly, but I cannot move or select the picture.

However, if I navigate to another web page in my web application, and then navigate back to the page where we use CKEditor, everything works fine. In other words if the CKEditor instance has been loaded before, everything works perfectly.

We are using AngularJS 1.4.4 together with [ng-ckeditor](https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor). This is the editorOptions we use:

```
$scope.editorOptions = {
    language: 'no',
    customConfig: '/statisk/app/common/ckeditor/ckeditor-config.js',
    extraPlugins: 'sharedspace,image2,widget,lineutils,uploadimage,uploadwidget,filetools',
    extraAllowedContent: 'a(*); span(*); figure(align_center, align_left); div{*}; figure; figcaption; img[alt,!src]{width,height};',
    toolbar: [
                   {name: 'paragraph', items: ['BulletedList', 'NumberedList']},
                   {name: 'links', items: ['Link']},
                   {name: 'insert', items: ['Image']}
               ],
    sharedSpaces: { top: 'toolbar_hovedtekst' }
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="hovedtekst" data-ng-show="modus.showEditorControls()">
    <div id="toolbar_hovedtekst"></div>
    <div class="ck_editor_hovedtekst test_hovedtekst" ckeditor="editorOptions" data-ng-model="hovedtekstCtrl.content"></div>
</div>
```

What could be wrong?